# How to send a image in ejs email template using node and express server?

Tags: node.js, express, email, ejs, nodemailer

I am sending an email using `nodemailer` and have an email template in `EJS`. When I render this template on my machine, I can see the `logo/image` too but when I send this template to an email address, images are not showing in the email.

I am hosting images using static `middleware` and here is the `middleware`:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

Is there any way to set the `logo/image` in the email?

Answer (score 3):

you have to give **full path** of image to ejs template when sending to email

```
 // common function used for send different emails 

 async sendMail(to:string, template:string, subject:string) {
    //create transport to send mail
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: config.get('SMTP_CONSTANTS.SERVICE'),
        auth: {
            user: config.get('SMTP_CONSTANTS.USERNAME'),
            pass: config.get('SMTP_CONSTANTS.PASSWORD')
        }
    });
    //define mail options
    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'Your Domain <support@domain.com>',
        to: to, // receiver
        subject: subject, // Subject line
        html: template
    };
    // send mail with defined transport object
    let response = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    return response;
}


 app.get('/test',(req,res)=>{
    let image_path = path.join(__dirname+'public/','logo.png');
    console.log('image_path==',image_path);

    let subject = 'Welcome To Website';
    let to = 'to send mail';
    let parameters = {
        name: 'James',
        image_path:image_path
    };
    let html = ejs.render(fs.readFileSync(__dirname+`/../views/auth/welcome.ejs`).toString(), parameters);
    let response:any = await this.sendMail(to, html, subject).then((data:any)=>{return data}).catch(error => { return error });
    return response;

});
```

Comment: getting __dirname as null, do you know any solution for that @Saurabh